# Installing Pygame on 64bit Windows with Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pip, python-3.4

I've downloaded the pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl file and attempted to install it by doing the following:

1. Place in same directory as command prompt's default (C:\Users\NAME)
2. Type **`pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl`** in cmd
3. It throws the error **`pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`**.

I've heard that you have to install the 32-bit version of Python to install Pygame, but that seems like a huge pain and I'd rather not have more headaches after hours of attempting to install Pygame.

I have 64-bit Windows 8.1 Pro and Python 3.4.3. How can I install Pygame?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help

https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/03/installing-the-windows-64-bit-version-of-pygame/

Although the Kiwi might be more interesting for you.

http://kivy.org

Comment: Those are the instructions I tried to follow. Thanks though :)